# Massless things have $F_{\rm net}=0$ right!

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

So, it is very clear that mass less things have net force on them as zero (0). Here the string is a mass less string so, the net force on it must be zero right!

The tension $T$ (at mass $M$), is for balancing the mass $M$, so who is cancelling the **T** at the  ceiling, so that net force on the string will be zero, as the string is mass less.

**If I am wrong anywhere then please correct me.**

Answer (score 2):

Draw separate free body diagrams for each component of the system. If each component is in equilibrium then the net force on it must be zero.

The forces on the mass are its weight $Mg$ downwards and the tension in the string $T$ upwards. These must net to zero. So $T=Mg$.

If the string exerts an upwards force $T$ on the mass then by Newton’s Third Law the mass exerts a downward force $T$ on the string. The ceiling exerts an upward force $T’$ on the string. Since the net force on the string is zero then $T’=T=Mg$.

Finally, the string exerts a downwards force $T’$ on the ceiling. And so whatever supports the ceiling must exert an upwards force of at least $T’$ (and probably more since the ceiling will have its own weight).

Comment: Always helpful sir,thank you.Guess I just forgot the 3rd law

Answer (score 1):

> The tension  (at mass ), is for balancing the mass , so who is cancelling the T at the ceiling

There are only two external forces acting on the string. The contact force at the top and the contact force at the bottom. Often they are labeled “$\vec T$“ and called “tension”, but technically tension is an internal force. It isn’t a big problem as long as you don’t get confused in later problems where you start dealing with internal forces and the actual tension.

It doesn’t make any sense to say that $\vec T$ balances $M$ because $\vec T$ is a force which is a vector with units of N and $M$ is a mass which is a scalar with units of kg. The gravitational force is $M\vec g$ but it also doesn’t make sense to say that $\vec T$ balances $M\vec g$ because $\vec T$ acts on the string and $M\vec g$ acts on the mass. They are equal but point in the same direction, and since they act on different objects they are not added to each other anyway.

Once you recognize that, then it is easy to see that the two contact forces (often called tension) are the only external forces acting on the string and they must cancel each other.

Comment: Your answer clearly points out my mistake,I forgot about the 3rd law.Thank you sir

Comment: It does make sense to say that T balances Mg. The string exerts an upward force of T on the mass which balances the downward force of gravity and the mass does not move.

Comment: @R.W. Bird that T is not either of the two T’s in the question.